# VFP / Disable message "File does not exist"

Tags: database, notifications, alert, visual-foxpro

I have tried to remove message from VFP - "File does not exist", with no luck.

I would like that if file does not exist it will skip to another line.

This is what I have tried:

```
SET SAFETY OFF
SET TALK OFF
SET SYSMENU OFF
SET NOTIFY OFF
```

Any solutions/suggestions ?

**Source used:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33a5zy93(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply check the existence of the file instead of hitting the error. i.e.:

```
local lcFile
lcFile = "c:\my path\my file.ext"
if file(m.lcFile)
   * do whatever with the file
endif
```

You could also wrap the error within an "on error" or "try-catch" block. i.e.:

```
* With On Error
on error note
Use myNonExistentFile
on error

* with try-catch
Try
    Use myNonExistentFile
Catch
Endtry
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that's helped.